# Model.fetch() callback not working after separating Backbone.js objects with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm splitting up my working Backbone.js application, into separate files for models, views and routers.

in my Router, I create a Model, perform its `.fetch()` and **expect to reach the callback function. This, however, never happens.**

```
return Backbone.Router.extend({
    self : this,

    initialize: function(){
        require(['models/mymodel'],
            function(MyModel) {
                var myModel = new MyModel();
                myModel.fetch({ success: self.callback, error: self.callback });
                console.log(myModel.get('myAttr'));
                //prints 'undefined', although can be seen in model.attributes
            }
        );
    },

    callback: function(){
        console.log('Callback reached!); //is never printed
    }
});
```

models/mymodel.js:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var $           = require('jquery'),
        Backbone    = require('backbone');

    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function(){
            return '/apicall';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major problem in your code is this bit:

```
self : this,
```

The `self` field will be created in the object literal but not to a value which is sensible for what you want to do. (And how would you get this value anyway?) At the beginning of your `initialize` function. Removing the line above from your code and setting `self` like this at the beginning of `initialize` should give you what you want:

```
initialize: function(){
    var self = this;
    // The rest is identical.
```